# Calling Constructor with Array Argument from Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, constructor, arguments, hashset

I'm a beginner in powershell and know C# moderately well. Recently I was writing this powershell script and wanted to create a Hashset. So I wrote($azAz is an array)

```
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$allset = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]($azAZ)
```

and pressed run. I got this message:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "HashSet`1" and the argument count: "52".
At filename.ps1:10 char:55
+ [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$allset = New-Object System.Collecti ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :         ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Then, I googled constructors in powershell with array parameters and changed the code to:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$allset = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string](,$azAZ)
```

Somehow, I now get this message:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "HashSet`1" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\youngvoid\Desktop\test5.ps1:10 char:55
+ [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$allset = New-Object System.Collecti ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Cannot find an overload for HashSet and the argument count 1? Are you kidding me? Thanks.

Comment: Why the comma in  (, $azAZ) ??

Comment: i dunno, i got it from a google search. i didnt even read the article through, but at least it got powershell to treat $azAZ as 1 argument. Perhaps it is because the comma indicates separate arguments?

Comment: It's because the comma is the array creation operator, so it makes $azAZ into an array with a single element of $azAZ - I think @($azAZ) is a clearer way to create an array-of-one-array.

Comment: apparently @($azAZ) doesnt work, "The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression" so a comma has to be used

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$allset = $azAZ
```

UPDATE:

To use an array in the constructor the array must be strongly typed. Here is an example:

```
[string[]]$a = 'one', 'two', 'three'
$b = 'one', 'two', 'three'

# This works
$hashA = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string] (,$a)
$hashA
# This also works
$hashB = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string] (,[string[]]$b)
$hashB
# This doesn't work
$hashB = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string] (,$b)
$hashB
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. anyway, what mistake was there in my code?

Comment: I think initializing collections was syntactical sugar that was added in c# 3. The compiler first creates the collection, then adds the elements behind the scenes. PowerShell just doesn't have syntax for this.

Comment: but the hashset class contains the constructor HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>) with 1 argument, just check msdn.

Comment: @testgo Ahh, you are correct. I've tested some more, and found that if the array is strongly typed, you can use it in the constructor. See the example in my updated answer.

Comment: If you want to specify the comparer, you can do "$hashA = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string] @($a, [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)"

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
C:\> $allset = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]
C:\> $allset.add($azAZ)
True
```

Comment: your method works too, but i intended to use the hashset constructor. your method however, is pretty and elegant

Comment: wait, your $allset.add($azAZ) adds all the elements in $azAZ as 1 element! something is definitely wrong here.

Comment: Yes, the add() do this. I misunderstood your needs. The right way to populate the HasSet from the arry values is in the Rynant answer.

Comment: @testgo You could also add the elements separately with `$azAZ| foreach{$allset.Add($_)}`

Comment: [`HashSet<T>.UnionWith(IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097.aspx): `$allset.UnionWith( [string[]]$azAZ )` (the cast is only needed if the array is an object array, and not strongly typed).

Comment: @EmperorXLII Great comment. It was the best answer in my opinion ;)